# Java socket system address

Tags: java, sockets, networking, serversocket

How to identify different system connected with same modem or sharing same internet connection? I applied `getHostAddress()` and 'getHostName()' on `Connection`(this is socket.getInetAddress()) but it seems like they both appear the same.

I just wanted to know whether different users who are connected are from same system sharing same IP.

Comment: Maybe you can show us some code and further explain the problem?

Comment: Are multiple connections being made?  i.e. can you use the tuple of address & port, or is further identification required?

Comment: What exactly is `Connection`?

Comment: @EJP sorry didn't specified , its a socket.getInetAddress result.

Comment: @Steve-o yes, in shared internet address and port will be same (not on single machine).

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with the functionality provided by IP (may it be TCP or UDP). That's why the IP address you get using `getHostAddress()` is the same.

Either the protocol you're implementing (if it's an already existing protocol specified by someone else) has to support some sort of client identification or (if it's you're own protocol) you have to implement this yourself, e.g. using some arbitrary checksums on client specific data (hardware GUID or similar).